# How can I do this pandas lookup with a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series `S`:

```
                               attr
first   last       visit
andrew  alexander  baseline    abc
andrew  alexander  followup    abc
bruce   alexander  baseline    abc
bruce   alexander  followup    xyz
fuzzy   dunlop     baseline    xyz
fuzzy   dunlop     followup    abc
```

and a DataFrame `df`:

```
                               abc   xyz
first   last       visit
andrew  alexander  baseline    1     7
andrew  alexander  followup    2     8
bruce   alexander  baseline    3     9
bruce   alexander  followup    4     10
fuzzy   dunlop     baseline    5     11
fuzzy   dunlop     followup    6     12
```

How can I get a new series `S2`, where for each index in `S`, the value is selected from `df`. If I was to use a loop, I'd do it this way:

```
lookup = pd.Series(index=S.index)
for ix, attr in S.iteritems(): 
    lookup.loc[ix] = df.loc[ix, attr]
```

Is there a more direct way to do this with a pandas function?

The result should look like this:

```
first   last       visit
andrew  alexander  baseline    1
andrew  alexander  followup    2
bruce   alexander  baseline    3
bruce   alexander  followup    10
fuzzy   dunlop     baseline    11
fuzzy   dunlop     followup    6
```

Comment: Aside: the representation of your series S makes it look more like a 1-column dataframe than a series.

Comment: Ah oops - that's what I get for writing that in a text editor instead of a python console :-}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [DataFrame.lookup()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
In [7]: pd.Series(df.lookup(s.index, s['attr']), index=df.index)
Out[7]:
first   last       visit
andrew  alexander  baseline     1
                   followup     2
bruce   alexander  baseline     3
                   followup    10
fuzzy   dunlop     baseline    11
                   followup     6
dtype: int64
```

if `s` is Series (not a DataFrame):

```
In [10]: pd.Series(df.lookup(s.index, s), index=df.index)
Out[10]:
first   last       visit
andrew  alexander  baseline     1
                   followup     2
bruce   alexander  baseline     3
                   followup    10
fuzzy   dunlop     baseline    11
                   followup     6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sorry, you got it. I'll remove mine.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, please undelete your answer - we did it at the same time :)

Comment: Hmmph.  This'll teach me to add comments to other people's answers, cost me valuable seconds. :-P

Comment: @DSM, yeah, that's true :-D

Comment: Note that if s is really a series, the `s['attr']` will fail, I think.

Comment: @DSM, yes, thank you. In OPs example `s` looks like a DF, that's why I did it this way...